# How do I stop excel formulas from changing?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula: =Sheet2!A2.
When I add a column at the start of Sheet2, the formula automatically changes to =Sheet!B2 (I tried adding $ signs but no luck), how can I prevent this? This also happens to me when I use Sheet2 data in a graph.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of is doing something like using the `INDIRECT` function ...

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2")
```

... it definitely won't move but it is a fairly heavy way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Or use an if() with a cell to trigger on/off:

Cell A1 set to “off” and:

In cell B2:

```
=if(A1="off","",Sheet!B2)
```

If A1 is set to on then it will reference cell b2 on the named sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (non-volatile) INDEX `=INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1048576,2,1)`